# Xcode 6.4 and 7.0 quit unexpectedly, I'm using Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7

I'm using cocoa pods and When I open My Project (.xcworkspace) after that I see this problem. If you want I can copy all text. I'm confused. I didn't do anything. Xcode open other file but this project cannot opened.

Edit: I add All Text.

```
Process:               Xcode [2164]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0 (8227)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8227000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       813293765
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2164]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-09-25 14:30:54.645 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        23EB5B80-9885-BE11-4263-41F6CC384A3B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       674459DE-8D63-40EE-AFC1-439575E256A3

Time Awake Since Boot: 6300 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        19

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A220
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-8184/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/TargetSnapshots/XCBuildFileRefDGSnapshot.m:474
Details:  Cannot call addBuildFileRef: when file refs are frozen
Object:   <XCBuildFileRefArrayDGSnapshot: 0x7fc02f0749a0>
Method:   -addBuildFileRef:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc02ae93100>{number = 12, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010ee5f904 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010da2b23e _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010da2b455 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000011771a234 -[XCBuildFileRefArrayDGSnapshot addBuildFileRef:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x00000001176f6c5f -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) groupDependencyNode:ifNecessaryForLaterProcessingWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x000000011770ae64 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _processOutputNodes:forRegionVariantName:processedPaths:originalBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000117709667 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:processedPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x000000011770bb1e -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x000000011770bfcb -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x00000001176f7694 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x000000011770ebaf -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x000000011770ff95 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x00000001176466b5 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x00000001176f0000 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x00000001175c3455 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x00000001175df677 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x00000001175ded3c -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x000000011763e342 -[XCBlockQueue _processNextBlockInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x000000011763e5c4 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 20  0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 21  0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
0

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ac8f61 _CASSynchronize + 112
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ac8eb1 CA::Context::synchronize(unsigned int, int) + 121
4   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ac8dff CABackingStoreSynchronize(CABackingStore*, CA::GenericContext*, unsigned int, int) + 75
5   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91abfab8 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 987
6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91abf6d7 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59
7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91abf694 x_blame_allocations + 81
8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ab343c CA::Layer::display_() + 1546
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86f9342b _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 617
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86f90026 -[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 834
11  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ab17fd CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 603
12  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ab0e81 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 35
13  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ab0612 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
14  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91ab03ae CA::Transaction::commit() + 390
15  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff91abef19 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 71
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eabb127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eabb080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff882d256f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff882d21ee ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff882d212b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86fbf8ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86fbee58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
24  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010dffb49b -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 247
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86fb4af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86f31244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8b2385c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84958232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90725a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fc02ee30dd0 :: NSOperation 0x7fc02f652ee0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de40d6e -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 131
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de27e34 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 254
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d995f82 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 67
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4b3c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d86e95f -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 111
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4613 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90722c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90726365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90727ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90733fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fc02f60ce40 :: NSOperation 0x7fc02e9aca80 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de40d6e -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 131
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de27e34 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 254
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d995f82 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 67
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4b3c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d86e95f -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 111
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4613 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90722c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90726365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90727ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90733fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaadeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaad37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddebb29 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000117bd032a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1103
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849573fa __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaadeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaad37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff93577420 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaadeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaad37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8708756b _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control Status Processing Queue :: NSOperation 0x7fc02f308ff0 (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de40d6e -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 131
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de27e34 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 254
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e4de249 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTree updateFileReferenceStatusesAndWaitForFinish:] + 225
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e4a41ca -[IDESourceControlWorkingTree mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:] + 8427
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e4e0a89 __102-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree updateLocalStatusForDirectory:cancelable:withWorkspace:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_4 + 64
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d846671 -[DVTOperation main] + 139
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4b3c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4613 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90722c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90726365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90727ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90733fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control File Reference Status Processing Queue :: NSOperation 0x7fc02f491910 (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495251a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90729c55 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 213
2   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010da664fe DVTSyncPerformBlock + 437
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e666395 __63-[IDESourceControlTreeItem updateFileReferences:withFilePaths:]_block_invoke + 1677
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb58b8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb5685 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4b3c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4613 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90722c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90726365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90727ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90733fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaadeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaad37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddebb29 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8de6124f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000122360901 -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495794a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 17:: Dispatch queue: <IDEBuildOperation:0x7fc02f12f370:REfc>-builder-queue :: NSOperation 0x7fc02f1b7b40 (QOS: UTILITY)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957166 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd69bdc -[NSRecursiveLock lock] + 22
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175c0460 -[PBXTargetBuildContext lockDependencyGraph] + 52
3   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175decaf -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] + 126
4   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175766ab -[PBXTarget(XCBuildables) buildWillStartForBuilder:buildParameters:] + 833
5   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000117779d45 -[Xcode3TargetBuildableSnapshot buildForBuilderWillStart:] + 1071
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e47f6ff -[IDEBuildableSnapshot performBuildForBuilder:buildCommand:buildOnlyTheseFiles:] + 128
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e47ee21 -[IDEBuilder main] + 1217
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4b3c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ddb4613 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90722c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90726365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90727ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90733fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011763e68f -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 19 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88b999b3 abort + 129
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ee5f4fb +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1481
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ee5fadb -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1202
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010da2b23e _DVTAssertionHandler + 562
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010da2b455 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
6   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011771a234 -[XCBuildFileRefArrayDGSnapshot addBuildFileRef:] + 110
7   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001176f6c5f -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) groupDependencyNode:ifNecessaryForLaterProcessingWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 823
8   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011770ae64 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _processOutputNodes:forRegionVariantName:processedPaths:originalBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:] + 717
9   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000117709667 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:processedPaths:] + 3984
10  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011770bb1e -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:withMacroExpansionScope:] + 137
11  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011770bfcb -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:withMacroExpansionScope:] + 1153
12  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001176f7694 -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 2223
13  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011770ebaf -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 65
14  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011770ff95 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 5055
15  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001176466b5 -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 2058
16  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001176f0000 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] + 3793
17  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175c3455 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] + 4302
18  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175df677 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] + 514
19  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x00000001175ded3c -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] + 267
20  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011763e342 -[XCBlockQueue _processNextBlockInThreadSlotNumber:] + 241
21  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011763e5c4 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 247
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84957136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011763e68f -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dd99e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff849524de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495164f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaadeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaad37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eaacbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eb64671 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86ca2b8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8495748a __semwait_signal + 10
1   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff89f5a407 0x7fff89f47000 + 78855
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b2405a _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b23fd7 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89b213ed thread_start + 13

Thread 19 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x0000000124e94628  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000018b03  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000124e94650  rsp: 0x0000000124e94628
   r8: 0x00000000000007ff   r9: 0x00007fc02ae93100  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff8c29b440  r13: 0x00007fc02f9afb10  r14: 0x0000000124e97000  r15: 0x00007fc02ddebd00
  rip: 0x00007fff84957286  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff750a9fd8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: You should open an issue with apple with the full details

Comment: I post this code below to apple forum but no one answer it. I'm afraid no one solve this problem.

Comment: Try deleting *.xcworkspace, Pods directory and Podfile.lock and after that run ´pod install´ again.

Comment: @PeterSegerblom I did again now. But i doesn't work :(

Comment: Depending on how big is your project and how much time and effort you'd like to invest into fixing the issue until there's a build that has it fixed (by the way, you might want to download and try any other Xcode version now and see what happens), you can backup and carefully edit the project.pbxproj file manually by removing all the files from compile source phase and add them back in batches, or move them into the new project and see if it is related to any particular files.

Comment: Espacially I spend my 6 months for this project. This project over 25.000 code line. I have to fix this problem. I'm not sure understand you @A-Live. You say that me I will build a new project. After that i put my all class in this project file, isn't it ?

Comment: That is one way to try to find the issue or create a project without one, yes, or you can research the project file structure and play around. Meanwhile put another Xcode version on download (I'd try 7.1 beta 2) and try it out.

Comment: I keep in my mind. I'm downloading to Xcode 7.1 Beta 2. I'm trying now. I will use this Xcode for run my project. I will give you an information about it. My project will run or not. @A-Live

Comment: I just filled a bug report to Apple. Related OpenRadar (not mine) : http://www.openradar.me/22582174

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple Said to me "This problem solved Xcode 7.1 Beta Version. We recommend download Xcode 7.1 Beta version. I tried after that I solved this Problem.

Comment: Please mark these answer as a solution, might save time for somebody with the same issue to read it first instead of going through all comments.

Comment: but submitting apps compiled with a Xcode-beta version lead to a review rejection is this right? In this case I'm forced to downgrade xcode. Do Apple mention this issue in the reply they gave to you? Thanks

Comment: but submitting apps compiled with a Xcode-beta version lead to a review rejection is this right? In this case I'm forced to downgrade xcode. Do Apple mention this issue in the reply they gave to you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `PBXBuildFile` section from `project.pbxproj`. This should allow you to open Xcode normally again. Then, you must reconfigure your build settings (compile sources, copy bundle resources, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Still don't know the technical reason.

In my project I had a Today-Extension and the crash reason was the Storyboard file.
Since I removed the Storyboard file, the Xcode 7 is not crashing anymore.

I think I have to create a new Storyboard and redecorate the Storyboard file.

I guest you have to remove your Storyboard with old Xcode (Xcode 6) and by trying and error see how is Xcode 7 react.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem opening projects with storyboards in XCode 7. If you open the project in 6.4 or 7.1 Beta and move any IB files that are in the Compile Sources build phase to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, XCode 7 won't crash anymore.